# How to check if a key exists in a mongodb object where the key is a value of some another field in the document while doing aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

First of all I know we can check if a key exists using the dot operator but in my case it is not working and I dont know why.

So far in the aggregation pipeline I have the following records.

```
{
  "my_key":"1234"
  "data":{
    1234:"abc"
    4567:"xyz"
  }
}

{
  "my_key":"6666"
  "data":{
    1234:"abc"
    4567:"xyz"
  }
}
```

I want to return the document where the `my_key` value does not exists in the data object. So according to the above example it should return the 2nd document.

I was trying using the `$match` operator as following but it does not seem to work.

```
$match :
{
  "data.$my_key":{$exists:false}
}
```

This does not work and I dont get why :(
Is it because the `my_key` value is a string and the keys in the `data` object are not strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VseKX04eLt0)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {//Reshape the data
      "data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$data"
      },
      "my_key": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {//matching
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "$data.k",
          "$my_key"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Another way](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zjaWYkuD7Cg)

[Wihtout unwind](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tW8og1BlCyz)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$data"
      },
      "my_key": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "output": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "data",
          "in": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$data.k",
              "$my_key"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "data": 1,
      "my_key": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      output: true
    }
  }
])
```

If you need original format of data, you can add the below as last stage

```
{
    $project: {
      "data": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      },
      "my_key": 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was able to do exactly this way but I cant unwind the `data` field :( cuz that does not work for me.

Comment: What you did is correct and an actual answer to the question but I want to achieve the same without unwinding

Comment: Updating the answer in sometime.

Comment: you found another solution?

Comment: Please check the update, it could be done better with few more attempts

Comment: Thanks for the solution, worked perfectly for me. Do you know the reason why the soln I used in my question did not work?

Comment: Reason: Mongo cannot evaluate `$` prefixed `keys`. That's why `$my_key` is not substituted with the value. Moreover, that's unexpected approach. But as we have growing use cases, mongo may implement or there could be some open JIRA tickets